# FTP PORT 425 ERROR

Tags: ftp, windows-server, port, putty

Что я делаю не так?
Если подключаюсь через PuTTY и все команды ввожу ручками, то, как я понял, не происходит DataChannelOpened/DataChannelClosed на сервере с портом 20.
Вначале лога первое подключение происходит через FileZilla, второе через PuTTY. Через FileZilla всё работает, файл 123.txt качается

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2019-09-24 08:26:42
#Fields: date time c-ip cs-username s-ip s-port cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status sc-win32-status sc-substatus x-session x-fullpath
2019-09-24 08:26:42 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.2 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:42 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.2 21 AUTH TLS 534 5 31 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:42 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.2 21 AUTH SSL 534 5 31 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:42 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.2 21 USER Fkyd 331 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 SYST - 215 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 FEAT - 211 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 OPTS UTF8+ON 200 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PWD - 257 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 TYPE I 200 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PORT 192,168,9,2,194,54 200 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:43 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 LIST - 226 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /
2019-09-24 08:26:46 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 CWD /admin 250 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /admin
2019-09-24 08:26:46 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PWD - 257 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:46 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PORT 192,168,9,2,194,55 200 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:46 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:46 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:46 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 LIST - 226 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /admin
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 CWD /docs 250 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /docs
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PWD - 257 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PORT 192,168,9,2,194,56 200 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 LIST - 226 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /docs
2019-09-24 08:26:48 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 MDTM 123.txt 213 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /docs/123.txt
2019-09-24 08:26:49 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 CWD /pub 250 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /pub
2019-09-24 08:26:49 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PWD - 257 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:49 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PORT 192,168,9,2,194,57 200 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:49 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelOpened - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:49 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 20 DataChannelClosed - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:26:49 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 LIST - 226 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d /pub
2019-09-24 08:26:53 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 0 0 b75b403f-97a1-4eb3-b928-b3a0034d5c5d -
2019-09-24 08:37:14 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.2 21 ControlChannelOpened - - 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:37:30 192.168.9.2 - 192.168.9.2 21 USER Fkyd 331 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:37:44 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PASS *** 230 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e /
2019-09-24 08:37:51 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 OPTS UTF8 200 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:37:57 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PWD - 257 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:38:06 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 TYPE I 200 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:38:21 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 PORT 192,168,9,2,194,54 200 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:38:25 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 list - 425 4294967295 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e /
2019-09-24 08:39:11 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 port 192,168,9,2,194,55 200 0 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
2019-09-24 08:39:13 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 LIST - 425 4294967295 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e /
2019-09-24 08:44:22 192.168.9.2 WIN-VAECRI97N5K\Fkyd 192.168.9.2 21 ControlChannelClosed - - 258 0 ec42bab9-ac95-45e4-99ce-166994d1772e -
```

Comment: Всё происходит на виртуальной машине с Windows Server. Брандмауэр отключен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было всегодишь второе подключения. Для этого я использовал неткат

```
nc.exe -l -p {номер порта, который вы указали через PORT}
```